# require file inside module?

Tags: ruby

I saw the following source code in someone's repository:

```
module Twitter
  module Bootstrap
      module Rails
        require 'twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine' if defined?(Rails)
      end
   end
end

require 'less-rails'
require 'twitter/bootstrap/rails/bootstrap' if defined?(Rails)
```

[Source](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/lib/twitter-bootstrap-rails.rb)

I want to know what's difference when we put `require` in a module?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference as far as the `require` is concerned, i.e., `require` always loads the file into the global namespace.

It should be noted that, in this case, the inner `require` will *always* run, since `Rails` at that point refers to the module it is within, so the `if` statement there will always evaluate to true.

This means the code is equivalent to the possibly less confusing:

```
module Twitter
  module Bootstrap
    module Rails
    end
  end
end

require 'twitter/bootstrap/rails/engine'
require 'less-rails'
require 'twitter/bootstrap/rails/bootstrap' if defined?(Rails)
```